# Importing two CSV files into Java and then parsing them. The first one works the second doesnt

Tags: java, csv, parsing

Im working on my code where I am importing two csv files and then parsing them

```
        //Importing CSV File for betreuen
        String filename = "betreuen_4.csv";
        File file = new File(filename);
        //Importing CSV File for lieferant
        String filename1 = "lieferant.csv";
        File file1 = new File(filename1);
```

I then proceed to parse them. For the first csv file everything works fine. The code is

```
         try {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String data = inputStream.next();
                String[] values = data.split(",");
                int PInummer = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
                String MNummer = values[0];
                String KundenID = values[2];
                //System.out.println(MNummer);
                //create the caring object with the required paramaters
                //Caring caring = new Caring(MNummer,PInummer,KundenID);
                //betreuen.add(caring);



            }
            inputStream.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException d) {
            d.printStackTrace();
          }
```

I then proceed to parse the other csv file the code is

```
                // parsing csv file lieferant
             try {
                 Scanner inputStream1 = new Scanner(file1);
                 while(inputStream1.hasNext()) {
                 String data1 = inputStream1.next();
                 String[] values1 = data1.split(",");
                 int LIDnummer = Integer.parseInt(values1[0]);
                 String citynames = values1[1];
                 System.out.println(LIDnummer);
                 String firmanames = values1[2];

                //create the suppliers object with the required paramaters
                //Suppliers suppliers = new 
                //Suppliers(LIDnummer,citynames,firmanames);
                //lieferant.add(suppliers); 
            }

            inputStream1.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException d) {
            d.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the first error I get is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>       at Verbindung.main(Verbindung.java:61)

So I look at my array which is *firmaname* at line 61 and I think, well it's impossible that its out of range since in my CSV file there are three columns and at index 2 (which I know is the third column in the CSV file) is my list of company names. I know the array is not empty because when i wrote

```
       `System.out.println(firmanames)`
```

it would print out three of the first company names. So in order to see if there is something else causing the problem I commented line 61 out and I ran the code again. I get the following error

```
   `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
  string: "Ridge"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
  at Verbindung.main(Verbindung.java:58)`
```

I google these errors and you know it was saying im trying to parse something into an Integer which cannot be an integer, but the only thing that I am trying to parse into an Integer is the code

```
      int LIDnummer = Integer.parseInt(values1[0]);
```

Which indeed is a column containing only Integers.
My second column is also indeed just a column of city names in the USA. The only thing with that column is that there are spaces in some town names like Middle brook but I don't think that would cause problems for a String type. Also in my company columns there are names like AT&T but i would think that the & symbol would also not cause problems for a string. I don't know where I am going wrong here.

I cant include the csv file but here is a pic of a part of it. The length of each column is a 1000.
[A pic of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1B6M.png)

Comment: If problematic CVS file is short, you can post it, so we can help. But the best idea is to use debug. Another thing is that writing our own CSV parser is bad idea, because your code doesn't handle case if ',' is part of value itself, but not delimeter.

Comment: Firstly the exception you got: It tells you even more, it says that you try to parse "Ridge" into an Integer, which isn't possible. Take a look at your data and search for "Ridge". He might be accidently in a column where otherwise are only numbers.

Comment: @Sergey Prokofiev I dont know how to include the CSV file but i included a pic. I'm learning Java by myself so thank you for the advice but at this point I dont understand why this is not working although it worked for the other csv.

Comment: @moneydhaze I see that Ridge comes from the second column of my csv and the full name of the first entry is actually Prairie Ridge. Can spaces in csv file cause problems when parsing?

Comment: @user296098 the picture is of a spreadsheet; that won't help us debug your parsing code. Please just paste the first, say, 10 lines of the actual text of the csv file into your question.

Comment: @user296098 default delimiter is a space, and you are not defining it by yourself, so yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanner by default splits its input by whitespace ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)). Whitespace means spaces, tabs and newlines.
So your code will, I think, split the whole input file at every space *and* every newline, which is not what you want.

So, the first three elements your code will read are

```
5416499,Prairie
Ridge,NIKE
1765368,Edison,Cartier
```

I suggest using method  [readLine of BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) then calling split on that.

The alternative is to explicitly tell Scanner how you want it to split the input

```
Scanner inputStream1 = new Scanner(file1).useDelimiter("\n");
```

but I think this is not the best use of Scanner when a simpler class (BufferedReader) will do.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Its true I got rid of all white spaces in the citynames and then everything worked fine. Just to understand for example the last line of code you posted. If I wanted the scanner to split by "," (a comma) then i just write Scanner inputStream1 = new Scanner(file1).useDelimiter(","); sorry if this question is silly but I am learning Java by my self and I don't have a big basis to go on and I have to learn as I go

Comment: You can do that but it will *only* split on comma, so you will get "NIKE\n1765368" with a newline in it. You would need to have `useDelimiter("[,\n]")` to split on either. But this will return data field-by-field, not line-by-line, so for example the first three iterations will give you the three fields from the first line and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would highly suggest you try and use an existing CSV parser, for example [this one](https://grokonez.com/java/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv-example).

But if you really want to use your own, you are going to need to do some simple debugging. I don't know how large your file is, but the symptoms you are describing lead me to believe that somewhere in the csv there may be a missing comma or an accidental escape character. You need to find out what line it is. So run this code and check its output before it crashes:

```java
     int line = 1;
try {
     Scanner inputStream1 = new Scanner(file1);

     while(inputStream1.hasNext()) {
         String data1 = inputStream1.next();
         String[] values1 = data1.split(",");
         int LIDnummer = Integer.parseInt(values1[0]);
         String citynames = values1[1];
         System.out.println(LIDnummer);
         String firmanames = values1[2];
         line++;
     }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.err.println("The issue in the csv is at line:" + line);
}
```

Once you find what line it is, the answer should be obvious. If not, post a picture of that line and we'll see...